# dereferencing an array

Tags: c, pointers

Using
gcc 4.4.3 c89:

I am just working on the following code below:

I just have some questions about dereferencing the src pointer. Which is declared in the calling function as:

```
char src[] = "device_id";
```

My confusion rests with dereferencing the src:

```
for(i = 0; src[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    printf("src %d: [ %s ]\n", i,  &src[i]);
}
```

`src` has decayed into a pointer. So src will be pointing to the first element in the array, which will be the character d:

```
src -> "device_id"
```

So when I do this `src[i]` I am dereferencing the value so it will return the character being currently pointing at. For this example when it gets to the nul it will break from the for loop.

```
For example i = 0
```

For `&src[i]` am I getting the address of the character instead of the character itself?
So where `src[i]` will dereference and return d, `&src[i]` will return the address of d.

Because `*dest[]` is an array of char pointers it is expecting an address. So here I am assigning an address of the character to the array of pointers to char.

```
dest[i] = &src[i];
```

Is there a difference to doing either this in the printf function for %s in using either `&src[i]` or `src[i]`:

```
printf("src %d: [ %s ]\n", i,  &src[i]);
```

or

```
printf("src %d: [ %s ]\n", i,  src[i]);
```

Source code:

```
void inc_array(char *src, size_t size)
{
    /* Array of pointers */
    char *dest[size];
    size_t i = 0;

    memset(dest, 0, size * (sizeof char*));

    /* Display contents of src */
    for(i = 0; src[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("src %d: [ %s ]\n", i,  &src[i]);
    }

    /* copy contents to dest */
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        dest[i] = &src[i];
    }

    /* Display the contest of dest */
    for(i = 0; *dest[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("dest %d: [ %s ]\n", i, dest[i]);
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For `&src[i]` am I getting the address of the character instead of the character itself? So where `src[i]` will dereference and return `d`, `&src[i]` will return the address of d.

`src[i]` is equivalent to `*(src + i)`, so `&src[i]` is the same as `&*(src + i)`, which can be reduced to `src + i`.  It is just performing pointer arithmetic and no dereferencing takes place.

`src[i]` gives you the character in `src` at index `i`, and `&src[i]` gives you a pointer to the `i`th character in `src`.

Comment: Why would anyone write `*(src + i)` when they could write `src[i]`?  It seems needlessly confusing to me.

Answer (score 2):

The format specifier %s wants to insert a string, so if you pass it &src[i], it will start at the i-th character of src and print until the null-terminator. You almost definitely want %c instead of %s, and src[i] instead of &src[i].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a difference.  `&src[i]` is the address of the character at `src[i]`, as you correctly say.  `src[i]` is the character itself.

For both printing with `"%s"` and assigning to a `char *` object, `&src[i]` is the correct formulation.

(By the way, `&src[i]` can also be written as `src + i`, if you like).